# Windows 8 hibernation option missing from power options

Tags: windows, windows-8, hibernate

Windows 8 Professional 32-bit running on Laptop. And the Hibernation option is missing from the Power Options in the System Settings. Even after I enable hidden power features by giving admin privileges.

How can I fix this?

[image: Hibernation not present in Windows 8]

Also the option to enable hibernation is missing from the advanced power plan options.

[image: Hibernation not available to be enabled]

---

**SOLUTION UPDATE**:

Thanks to [magicandre1981 and his solution below](https://superuser.com/a/511133/109803) I have found that you need to enable hibernation using a command prompt.

1. Get to the Start menu, type 'CMD' this will begin the search.
2. Press the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to start the command prompt with administrative privileges.
3. Type `powercfg -h on` and press enter
4. [Follow Alexey Ivanov's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/511148/109803)
5. [Follow avirk's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/511882/109803)

Comment: Did you install the display drivers?

Comment: Do both of the suggested answers together and you'll have a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the solution in its entirety above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you enabled Hibernation?

```
powercfg -h on
```

Comment: This was what I was missing. I have added the entire solution above for any future visitors.

Comment: Note that on Windows 8 the command is as CBuHKa posted below: "powerconfig /hibernate on"

Answer (score 4):

Hybrid sleep is most likely enabled.

1. From the screen above, return to Power Option screen by clicking **Power Options** in the address bar.
2. And then click **Change power plan** link next to the active power plan.
   Alternatively you can click **Choose when to turn off display** or **Change when the computer sleeps** on the left pane.
3. Click **Change advanced power options**.
4. Expand **Sleep** and then **Allow hybrid sleep**:
   [image: Advanced Power Options: Allow hybrid sleep]
   It has to be set to **Off** if you want to see **Hibernate** option separately.

When hybrid sleep is enabled, **Sleep** command combines sleeps and hibernate: the system saves RAM to `hiberfil.sys` and then puts the computer to sleep. This option is useful for desktop computers which do not have battery:

- If power supply is not interrupted, the system will wake up almost instantly (from sleep);
- If power supply is interrupted, the system will read RAM from `hiberfil.sys` and resume from hibernation.

For laptops, it makes sense to disable hybrid sleep: it has battery, and thus the system will enter low power mode faster. If the battery level becomes low, Windows will automatically hibernate the laptop.

<sub>The screen shot and the names of links are from Windows 7. This hasn't changed much in Windows 8, I have to no access to Windows 8 system at the moment.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If hibernate worked but accidentally disappeared, as it happened on my pc you should open administrator promt and type there "powercfg /hibernate on" to restore.

Answer (score 1):

if

```
powercfg -h on
```

command gives an error you should first

```
powercfg -h off
```

then

```
powercfg -h on
```

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).