# Windows 8.1 Sony vaio with no CMOS battery

Tags: battery, hibernate, sony-vaio, cmos

I have an issue with one of my screws that prevents me from opening my PC for any hardware maintenance; therefore, I can't plug the CMOS battery back.

Why I removed the battery? I had forgotten my BIOS password; therefore, I removed the battery with some tools.

Now, my laptop is running without any CMOS battery on it. The time is not being affected.

Recently, I got the hibernation option disappeared from the list of options, and with the help of the following link, I was able to bring it back

[Windows 8 hibernation option missing from power options](https://superuser.com/questions/511076/windows-8-hibernation-option-missing-from-power-options)

My questions:

1. Could the hibernation issue caused by the battery removal?
2. what other issues the battery might be causing?

P/S: my Vaio model number = Sony VAIO Fit 15E SVF1521ECXW

If you have any advice in this regard, please let me know.

Comment: I would expect that if you ever remove the main battery and A.C. supply at the same time then your clock will reset and all your other firmware based settings like memory clock and processor clock speeds could be reset to default. It could cause any number of curious but minor performance issues.

Comment: @Mokubai, thank you for answering. The only time the clock reset happened is when my battery died and my PC was not shutdown. I will keep monitoring and put back the battery the soonest.